# SPI broadcast: talk to many slaves

Tags: spi

I need to do similar things to this question on Stack Overflow:
"[Using Serial Peripheral Interface (SPI) to talk to several slaves simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50312318/2717568)
"
I have no confirmation if it works. Has someone succeeded with this method?

I go further with my request...for some reasons:

1. all the MISO lines have to be connected together
2. no CS pin is used to select the slaves

If I ensure, during the "broadcast", that MISO of slaves becomes high impedance whatever is CS level (programatically or using an external tri-state buffer). Do you think it will work well?

Comment: That can work provided it is implemented in a proper way. A slave responds to a proper input signal sequence. In this scheme you simply provide the same signals to many slaves at once. One slave does not even "know" that there are other slaves.

Comment: user2717568 -  In the title, you say that the SPI slaves are "*silent*". Then later you say that your design requires "*all the MISO lines have to be connected together*". Since MISO is an *output* from an SPI slave, you don't use (or connect) MISO from a truly *silent* slave. Therefore your situation is unclear, as the question and title appear to contradict each other. It would help if you edit the question, add a link to the datasheet(s) of your SPI slaves, add your planned schematic, and explain why you have the requirements (1) and (2). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, SPI was not designed for broadcast transmissions.
You can do this, with few caveats:

1. The MISO lines are not connected together. You will get collisions if they are connected.
2. All the slaves are similar devices, weird stuff can happen when the wrong opcode is sent to a device.

You should use a separate CS line for each slave, and not tie them all together, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast SPI data from master to multiple slaves by making sure MOSI pin has its signal integrity intact till it reaches the slaves. it is recommended to use multiple buffers depending on the requirement.

For further requrest:

> 1. all the MISO lines have to be connected together

You can connect all MISO lines together risking over current on the MISO pins on the slaves due to small difference of timing from each slaves. Even if you have same part used as multiple devices and they are giving same reply, still there will almost always be small difference in timing of response of all of them. So, technically, you can't read data back from your multiple slaves simultaneously.

> 2. no CS pin is used to select the slaves

You can hard wire CS pin in the circuit for slaves but before that make sure from their datasheet that none of the transaction you intend to do requires CS pin to transition from enable to disable. Sometimes, some SPI slaves use CS pin for synchronization.